# How to tag source code using gitlabCI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

We got gitlab new to our environment and trying to create some CI CD pipelines using gitlab CI. I have got some better progress with running some maven goals, creating pipelines and archiving artifacts using my .gitlab-ci.yml as below. I tried to give give tags after script which doesnt work. Now, I am trying to figure out how can I automate git tags to my sourcecode. I would like to create tag for sourcecode after master branch got successful build. we are using Semantic versions to tag our source code. Finally, so whenever master got successful build I would like to create a tag to my master branch.

```
image: maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine

stages:
 - build
 - deploy
 - tag

maven_build:
  stage: build

  script:
   - mvn clean package
artifacts:
 paths:
 - target/*.jar

after_script:
   - ls -a
   - cd target && ls -a
   - git --version
   - git tag -a 1.0.15 -m "Version created by gitlab-ci Build"
   - git push origin 1.0.15
only:
  - master
```

logs:

```
Running after script...
$ ls -a
.
..
.git
.gitignore
.gitlab-ci.yml
 LICENSE
README.md
pom.xml
src
target
$ cd target && ls -a
.
..
apidocs
classes
generated-sources
generated-test-sources
javadoc-bundle-options
maven-archiver
maven-simple-0.2-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
maven-simple-0.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
maven-simple-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
maven-status
surefire-reports
test-classes
Uploading artifacts...
target/maven-simple-0.2-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar: found 1 matching files 
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=60598296 
responseStatus=201 Created token=Gu-eH1es
```

Job succeeded

Comment: Please add the log

Comment: attached is the logs@030

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tried to change docker image and added couple steps for git tag. Below is the answer worked for me,

```
image: maven

stages:
- build
- deploy
- tag

maven_build:
stage: build

  script:
   - mvn clean package
   artifacts:
  paths:
   - target/*.jar

  after_script:
   - ls -a
   - cd target && ls -a
   - git --version
   - git remote remove origin
   - git remote set-url origin https://"username:passwd"@gitlab.com/accountname/projectname
   - git tag -a 1.0.15 -m "Version created by gitlab-ci Build"
   - git push origin 1.0.15
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: If you want to set the origin to a Gitlab access token use `oauth2:${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}` as basic auth.

Comment: Also I would like to note, that you do not need to remove the `origin`, you can just `git remote add api-origin https://...` that shaves off one line. Later use that new origin in `git push api-origin 1.0.15`.

Comment: And I needed to add two lines, `git config user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"` and `git config user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"` to get it to push nicely.

Comment: you can also skip a job/pipeline execution adding `-o ci.skip` in your git push command

Comment: This is problematic as it puts username/password in a source repository... unsafe for obvious reasons, and outright forbidden if you work for security-aware customers or companies.

Comment: How can we create tags in gitlab from Jenkins Pipeline after successful builds @pandey

Answer (score 3):

Combining the answer of https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/3854/10932 and the comment of Overbryd along with a slight modification worked for me. Here, instead of using using **git remote set-url** command, I used **git remote add**.

The code will look like this:

```
image: maven

stages:
- build
- deploy
- tag

maven_build:
stage: build

  script:
   - mvn clean package
   artifacts:
  paths:
   - target/*.jar

  after_script:
   - ls -a
   - cd target && ls -a
   - git --version
   - git remote remove origin
   - git remote add origin https://"username:passwd"@gitlab.com/accountname/projectname.git
   - git config user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
   - git config user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
   - git tag -a 1.0.15 -m "Version created by gitlab-ci Build"
   - git push origin 1.0.15
  only:
    - master
```

Thanks to both.

Comment: We can also use Gitlab personal access tokens instead of directly using Gitlab's username and password. 
Link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html

Answer (score 2):

`git push origin 1.0.15` should work and a new tag should be added to the tags in gitlab

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/university/training/topics/tags.html

> ```
> git checkout master
>
> # Lightweight tag
> git tag my_lightweight_tag
>
> # Annotated tag
> git tag -a v1.0 -m ‘Version 1.0’
> git tag
>
> git push origin --tags
> ```

Comment: I think the runner get only a read key to clone the repo, the runner won't be able to push back on the repo IIRC

Comment: Could be possible, but this is not shown in the log. @pandey Could you post the complete log?

Comment: @030 git commands are  not working when i defined it in after script...do i need to create as job1 and job 2?

Comment: If git is installed in the docker image and the authentication succeeds then it should work.

Comment: @030 This won't generally work, the runner indeed typically only has read-only access to the repository.  The error in the logs looks like: `$ git push origin --tags
\nremote: You are not allowed to upload code.`

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer ssh connection use this:

```
after_script:
  - git --version
  - git remote remove origin
  - git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git
  - git tag -a v-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA -m "Version created by gitlab-ci Build"
  - git push --tags
```

Answer (score 0):

I find myself in the same situation, where after publishing a build of an artifact, I want to tag the commit with a version number tag.

One solution I'm considering is to create a service (either inside or outside of GitLab) that's capable of pushing a tag to any repository, but **can't do anything else**.  The service itself would possess credentials allowing it to write to repositories, so that each project build doesn't need to be granted write access to the repo.

I like this solution because GitLab doesn't seem to offer a permission level that can push tags onto existing commits, without also granting the ability to push commits containing new content.  Generic write access is more permission than we need or want for this use case, so if we had it, we'd probably need to limit the scope by creating a user or a token *for each repository* with permissions to commit to just that repository.  Then we'd need to manage all those users or tokens over time, which seems like it could get unwieldy.