# Is there any other approach for tagging git branch using pipeline without credentials in pipeline code?

Tags: git, gitlab, cicd

I was trying to tag a git branch using Gitlab CI. With the help of this answer from this community,

> [How to tag source code using gitlabCI](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/how-to-tag-source-code-using-gitlabci)

I can successfully tag a git branch from Gitlab CI pipeline. But In that method, I noticed that we need to provide the gitlab credentials in that pipeline code. I know, we can pass that as Gitlab environment variables.

But I just need to know, is there any other method to do this operation? With a Key or Token or something rather than direct username and password?

Not sure whether my question legit? I was thinking about the security side of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you need is just a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html), or if you're a maintainer, possibly a [Deploy Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/). It's *much* safer than embedding user credentials.

Comment: Personal Access token worked for me, thanks. As Deploy tokens don't provide write_repository scope, that didn't worked. I'm explaining the steps here: https://medium.com/@neronjoseph.sep/tag-your-git-repo-using-gitlabs-ci-cd-pipeline-a7963c2274d2